# problema con lista en python

Tags: python, python-3.x

El ejercicio me pide que almacene en una lista 5 números leídos y que muestre las POSICIONES del numero mayor, pero no se como hacerlo,
ya que si el numero mayor esta repetido 1 vez, el programa me funciona,  pero si esta repetido varias veces, no se como hacer que me muestre todas las posiciones donde se repite. Este es mi código:

```
try:

    lista=[]
    pos=1

    for i in range(5):
        numero=int(input("Digite un numero entero: "))
        lista.append(numero)

    print("El mayor numero esta en las posiciones:")
    mayor=lista[0]

    for l in range(len(lista)):
        if lista[l] > mayor:
            mayor=lista[l]
            pos+=1
    print(pos)  

except ValueError:
    print("El valor digitado debe ser numerico")
```

Comment: Solo un consejo. Un error que muchos cometemos al principio es el de meter grandes porciones de código dentro de "try - except" (o "try catch" en otros lenguajes). Estas instrucciones solo se deben usar específicamente en la parte que puede fallar y que no está bajo nuestro control y salir de ellas lo más pronto posible; no en el resto de las sentencias, por ejemplo: una entrada de usuario (y aún así se pudiera omitir pasando un filtro antes de evaluar la entrada), tratar de leer un archivo, tratar de acceder un socket apagado, tratar de escribir una base de datos, etc.

Answer (score 4):

El tema es que tienes dos problemas que no pueden ser resueltos en una misma interación:

- Saber cual es el mayor
- Saber las posiciones del mismo

El valor mayor solo lo sabrás si recorres la lista completa, lo cual quiere decir que debemos hacer un primer ciclo para encontrar el mayor y un segundo ciclo para obtener las posiciones de este. Además como puedes tener varias ocurrencias del valor mayor, esto lo deberíamos manejar en una nueva lista `mayores`.

```
lista = [5,3,7,9,2,3,9,0]
mayor = lista[0]

# Buscamos el mayor
for l in range(len(lista)):
  if lista[l] > mayor:
    mayor=lista[l]

# Obtenemos las posiciones del mismo
mayores = []
for l in range(len(lista)):
  if lista[l] == mayor:
    mayores.append(l)

print(mayor)
print(mayores)

9
[3, 6]
```

Por supuesto en Python hay muchas formas de resolver este problema, ésta en particular podríamos decir es la abstracción más elemental y de bajo nivel, pero también podríamos hacer algo así:

```
mayores = [i for i in range(len(lista)) if lista[i] == max(lista)]
print(mayores)
[3, 6]
```

En este caso, obtenemos todas las posiciones `i` de `i for i in range(len(lista))` que cumplan con que el valor del elemento sea igual al valor máximo `if lista[i] == max(lista)`

Comment: muchas gracias amigo llevaba mucho rato tratando de hacer este ejercicio

Answer (score 2):

Si pueden ser varias posiciones tienes que almacenarlas en una lista

```
pos = []

for l in range(len(lista)):
    if lista[l] > mayor:
        mayor=lista[l]
        pos= [l] 
    elif lista[l] == mayor:
        pos.append(l)
```

Si es mayor almacenas el valor en una variable y r inicias con la posición "l" , si el valor es igual al mayor entonces añades la posición a la lista